# Covert html in javascript to HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, svelte-component

I'm working on the tooltips and from the backend I'll get data in with html tags. I need to show in the tooltip with its corresponding data in its respective tags. For example, I'll get hello user click here from the backend. I've to show as hello user in h1 format and click here should be a anchor. I tried with both functions and replace its not working.

With function:

```
<h1 id="data">

</h1>
    function convertToPlain(html){
        var tempDivElement = document.createElement("div");
        tempDivElement.innerHTML = html;
        return tempDivElement.textContent || tempDivElement.innerText || "";
    }
    var htmlString= "<div><h1>Bears Beets Battlestar Galactica </h1>\n<p>Quote by Dwight Schrute<a> click here<a></p></div>";
    let dataVal = convertToPlain(htmlString)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dataVal;
```

With replace:

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-fast-u8fie?file=/App.svelte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made below snippet by copy-paste your code and just update return statement inside `convertToPlain` function, also I added `href` attribute to `<a>` in the `htmlString` content.

```js
function convertToPlain(html) {
  var tempDivElement = document.createElement("div");
  tempDivElement.innerHTML = html;
  return tempDivElement.innerHTML;
}
var htmlString = "<div><h1>Bears Beets Battlestar Galactica </h1>\n<p>Quote by Dwight Schrute<a href='#'> click here<a></p></div>";
let dataVal = convertToPlain(htmlString)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dataVal;
```

```html
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```